# Pass List of Data from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass `List<T>` data from view to controller.

I am getting data from controller to view in this manner:

```
@model IList<Test.Models.Incentive>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  <div class="tab-content"> 
    <table class="grid">      
      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
        <tr>
          <td class="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.From, new { @class = "wide" })</td>
          <td class="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.To, new { @class = "wide" })</td>
          <td class="left">@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.IncentiveAmount, new { @class = "wide" })</td>
        </tr>
      }
    </table>
  </div>
}
```

I get the data properly in the grid.
Now when i change/update data in grid i want to save it back on button click when I do that I get the value as null.

```
public class Incentive
{        
  public decimal From { get; set; }
  public decimal To { get; set; }
  public decimal IncentiveAmount { get; set; }  
}

public List<Incentive> GetIncentive()
{
  List<Incentive> obj = new List<Incentive>();
  obj.Add(new Incentive {From = 7m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  obj.Add(new Incentive { From = 17m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  obj.Add(new Incentive { From = 27m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  obj.Add(new Incentive { From = 37m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  obj.Add(new Incentive { From = 47m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  obj.Add(new Incentive { From = 57m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  obj.Add(new Incentive { From = 67m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  obj.Add(new Incentive { From = 77m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  obj.Add(new Incentive { From = 87m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  obj.Add(new Incentive { From = 97m, To = 9.9m, IncentiveAmount = 25.0m });
  return obj;         
}

// For Saving Data getting in controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(IList<Incentive> item)
{
  try
  {
    // item is coming null ?????
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
  return View();
}
```

How to get this data ?

Comment: You need to use a `for` loop so the controls are correctly named with indexers - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From) ...}`

Comment: @Stephen : i did not get you ?

Comment: Your using a `foreach` loop to generate the controls, which generate duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and `name` attributes (cannot bind to a collection). You need to use a `for` loop (inspect the html before and after to understand)

Comment: @Stephen : that is not an issue i am getting the data correctly issue is while saving back i am not able to get the data in controller.

Comment: OMG. Try it! The reason it null is because your using a `foreach` loop. It needs to be a `for` loop.

Comment: OK. But how it will identify the property "from"  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From...I am not able to get property from here ?

Comment: Sorry, its `m => m[i].From`

Comment: Thanks. That Worked. Can you please let me know how i can save that list of data what is the best approach. I have List<Incentive> if there are some changes in the list i want to save full list to the table ??

Comment: Far to many different approaches to give you advice (compare with the original list in the controller, include a hidden `IsDirty` property that gets updated by javascript if an input is changed, etc)

Comment: I want to use multiple models in view i am using Tuple/ViewModel approach but using for loop approach i am not able to get count property.Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: A `Tuple` is the worst possible approach for a multiple model approach. Use a view model with properties for each model/collection.

Comment: I am using Viewmodel approach defining my two models in one ViewModel and refering that @model ViewModel in .cshtml and using for loop like this :   for (int i = 0; i < Model.Incentive.Count; i++)
                                        {@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Incentive[i].From } but again same issue not getting data on save ???

Comment: But you POST method parameter is `IList<Incentive>`. Your parameter needs to be whatever you model is (or you need to use `[Bind(Prefix = "Incentive")]